# Is there any multiple orthogonal polynomials function in r ? (other than poly)

Tags: r

I would like to generate multiple orthogonal polynomials for a 50x30 matrix.

The result should have 30 + 30 + 30C2 = 30 + 30 + 435 = 505 columns and 50 rows.
I tired `poly` in the `R` base packages and it ran out of memory even for first order. Is there any function in R could do multiple orthogonal polynomials?(tried `orthopolynom`
, but it only work for univariate) or it is just too difficult to do it? Thanks

Here is my code

```
n=50
k=30
x=matrix(rnorm(n*k),nrow=n,ncol=k)
poly(x,degree=1)
Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :  cannot allocate vector of length 1073741824
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your 30C2 terms you don't want orthogonal polynomials, but rather all the two-way interaction terms:

```
paste( combn( paste0("X", 1:30), 2, FUN=paste, collapse="*"), collapse="+")
```

For the orthogonal polynomials of degree 2 you might want:

```
paste( "poly(", paste0("X", 1:30), ", degree=2)", collapse="+")
```

You would need to construct an R formula with `as.formula` if you wnatted to use it for regression.

I am not sure if this will give your orthogonal polynomials or not but it would give you a formula expression of the desired complexity:

```
as.formula( paste(" ~ (", paste0("X", 1:30 , collapse="+"), ")^2", collapse=""))
#--------------
~(X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X11 + X12 + 
X13 + X14 + X15 + X16 + X17 + X18 + X19 + X20 + X21 + X22 + 
X23 + X24 + X25 + X26 + X27 + X28 + X29 + X30)^2
```

That would expand to all the linear terms, all the squared terms and all the two-way combinations. See `help(formula)`. And to see what that expands to use:

```
terms( as.formula( 
         paste(" ~ (", paste0("X", 1:30 , collapse="+"), ")^2", collapse="")
       ) )
```