# Fitting a multivariate polynomial of generic degree in R without having to write the explicit formula

Tags: r, regression

I would like to fit a multivariate polynomial of arbitrary degree and in an arbitrary number of variables, to some data. The number of variables can be high (for example 40) and the code should work for different numbers of variables (e.g., 10, 20, 40, etc.)., so it's not possible to write out the formula explicitly. For a degree 1 polynomial (i.e., the classic linear model), the solution is trivial: suppose I have my data in the dataframe df, then

```
mymodel <- lm(y ~ ., data = df)
```

Unfortunately I don't know of a similar compact formula when the polynomial is of arbitrary degree. Can you help me?

Comment: I think this is answered in a response to an earlier question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158465/is-there-any-multiple-orthogonal-polynomials-function-in-r-other-than-poly Both the two-way interactions and the polynomial term constructions are illustrated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that answer doens't work...try `terms( as.formula(paste(" ~ (", paste0("X", 1:3 , collapse="+"), ")^2", collapse="")))` you will see that only linear and interaction terms are included, but not quadratic ones. What a pity, it was so close...

Comment: I will demonstrate in an answer panel. You were expected to notice that there were two options presented and that you would need to combine them for your particular request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This combines both options from my earlier posting (interactions and polynomial terms) in a hypothetical situation where the column names look like "X1", "X2", ...., "X30". You would take out the terms() call which is just in there to demonstrate that it was successful:

```
terms( as.formula( 
     paste(" ~ (", paste0("X", 1:30 , collapse="+"), ")^2", "+", 
            paste( "poly(", paste0("X", 1:30), ", degree=2)", 
                    collapse="+"), 
          collapse="")
      )         )
```

You could use an expression like `names(dfrm)[!names(dfrm) %in% "y"]` instead of the inner `paste0` calls.

Note that the interaction terms are constructed by way of the R formula process in with the (...)^2 mechanism which is no creating squared terms but rather all of hte two way interactions:

```
as.formula( 
        paste(" ~ (", paste0("X", 1:30 , collapse="+"), ")^2", "+", paste( "poly(", paste0("X", 1:30), ", degree=2)", collapse="+"), collapse="")
        ) 
#----output----
~(X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X11 + X12 + 
    X13 + X14 + X15 + X16 + X17 + X18 + X19 + X20 + X21 + X22 + 
    X23 + X24 + X25 + X26 + X27 + X28 + X29 + X30)^2 + poly(X1, 
    degree = 2) + poly(X2, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X3, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X4, degree = 2) + poly(X5, degree = 2) + poly(X6, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X7, degree = 2) + poly(X8, degree = 2) + poly(X9, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X10, degree = 2) + poly(X11, degree = 2) + poly(X12, 
     degree = 2) + poly(X13, degree = 2) + poly(X14, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X15, degree = 2) + poly(X16, degree = 2) + poly(X17, 
     degree = 2) + poly(X18, degree = 2) + poly(X19, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X20, degree = 2) + poly(X21, degree = 2) + poly(X22, 
     degree = 2) + poly(X23, degree = 2) + poly(X24, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X25, degree = 2) + poly(X26, degree = 2) + poly(X27, 
     degree = 2) + poly(X28, degree = 2) + poly(X29, degree = 2) + 
    poly(X30, degree = 2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this. `poly(X2, degree=2)` is *not* the term X2^2. It is an orthogonal polynomial of degree 2 (see `help(poly)` ). I cannot check right now, but Monday I will verify if fitting your formula in a simple two variables case, i.e., `as.formula(paste(" ~ (", paste0("X", 1:2 , collapse="+"), ")^2", "+", paste( "poly(", paste0("X", 1:2), ", degree=2,raw=TRUE)", collapse="+"), collapse="")` returns the same coefficients as fitting the explicit formula `as.formula("~ (X1 +X2)^2 +I(X1^2)+I(X2^2)")`.

Comment: Yes. I use orthogonal polynomials to avoid the statistical error of including terms like `I(x^2)`. There would be a potential overlap between the interaction terms and the linear terms that are created by the poly terms but the formula processing mechanism recognizes that and drops one of them. DO NOT use `I(x^2)`.

Comment: Oh, great, I didn't know that! Well, then that's perfect. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also, DO NOT try to interpret coefficients arising from a model that has interaction terms. By themselves they are basically meaningless, and you should instead be looking at the predictions and comparing differences in model fit between the larger and reduced models.

Comment: Now that I think of it, all this works for multivariate polynomials of degree 2. In case of degree 3, I would be missing terms such as x1^2*x3. However, for now I will go with this solution.

Comment: Trying to interpret a result that includes such monstrosities seems a pathway to madness. It would nonetheless be possible if you nested the polynomial term construction inside the call to (...)^2 or (....)^3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `makepoly` that generates a formula with polynomial terms based on a formula and a data frame.

```
makepoly <- function(form, data, degree = 1) {
  mt <- terms(form, data = data)
  tl <- attr(mt, "term.labels")
  resp <- tl[attr(mt, "response")]
  reformulate(paste0("poly(", tl, ", ", degree, ")"), 
              response = form[[2]])
}
```

A test data set:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), 
                 x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
```

Create the formula and run the regression:

```
form <- makepoly(y ~ ., df, degree = 2)
# y ~ poly(x1, 2) + poly(x2, 2) + poly(x3, 2)


lm(form, df)
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = form, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  poly(x1, 2)1  poly(x1, 2)2  poly(x2, 2)1  
# 0.1322        0.1445       -5.5757       -5.2132  
# poly(x2, 2)2  poly(x3, 2)1  poly(x3, 2)2  
# 4.2297        0.7895        3.9796
```

Comment: Hi,Sven, I don't think it's correct. A third degree polynomial in 2 variables has 10 coefficients, not 7. I think you're missing the interaction terms, i.e., x1*x2, x1*x3, x2*x3.